# Disconnect the [intermittent] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [intermittent](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/intermittent) tag has 7 questions. It seems too meta to be useful.

Should we keep it around? Or is it time to end the connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, it gives no useful information at all. And its small enough not to flood the front page. I'd be inclined to wait a day or two, and if no one has a good reason to keep it, nuke it.

Comment: This is complete